# Flutter web get obscureText from password in unobscure form on button press in variable

Tags: flutter, web, passwords

I need to use normal plain text to hash my password when pressing signup.  But can not get the obscure text in a variable as unobscure text.  My code :

```
TextFormField(
  obscureText: true,
  controller: passwordController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Password",
    isDense: true,
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
    ),
  ),
),
```

When I enter 1234 as password and call String password = passwordController.text; my result is ***4. I am unable to get it to print 1234.

Can anyone assist please.

I tried now almost everything even passwordfield, but the text recieved with the controller stay ***4, so how do people in flutter actually get the normal text back from the obscured text?  For I can use 1114 in the verify password even though the password is 1234, for it checks ***4.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please see below .

```
     class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
      }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
    
      late String password = '';
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        passwordController.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            password = passwordController.text.toLowerCase();
          });
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  obscureText: true,
                  controller: passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Password",
                    isDense: true,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text('The pasword that I entered is : ' + password)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. I did the onchange and then grabbed the last entry in string and added it to another string and it also worked. This I find on windows google chrome but on hu-ewei chrome it works correctly.  you think it could be a bug?

Comment: Sorry, this solution still output ***4.

Comment: Strange yes . It works from my side

Comment: Very strange in deed, same with show password, it changes the bool value from true to false and print the obscured and unobscured values but it does not show the password in the textfield.  Going nuts this side for on laptop one behaviour and on device another.

Comment: Hi what version flutter are you using?  Tried with flutter 3.3.7 dart 2.18.4 and flutter 3.7.0 dart 2.19.0.  If you use a different flutter version please let me know which one

Comment: well tested now with flutter 2.0.1 and it works. From flutter 2.5.0, 2.8.0 3.3.7 and 3.7.0 it does not work, the output for '1234' is ***4.  Is this a bug or is there a work arround?

Comment: I have Flutter 3.38

Comment: Thanks, will try that one for the ones I tried that works is flutter 2.0.1, flutter 2.0.6 and flutter 2.20, from 2.2.2 I get the problem behaviour.

Comment: Hi, what enviroment are you using? and which channel?  For flutter stable 3.3.8 envirment 2.18.4 still not giving correct result. Are yu using maybe master or beta.  Also are you running for web flutter run -d chrome or for device flutter run?

Comment: Thank you did help, I changed to 3.3.8 master channel and now it works.

Comment: I'm also having a big problem currently with one of my projects that's giving me headaches .

Comment: Jip that is programming, let me know if I maybe can help. Any idea on the show password, cant get it to work. the bool value changes but the textfield do not rebuild even with setState(). O the master is 3.8.0 not 3.3.8 as i thought